# Using a segmented control to switch collection views

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

On iOS what would be the correct / most efficient way to switch collection views using a segmented control located in the navigation bar?

Comment: are you asking about how to add a segmented control to a nav bar and react to the control or are you asking about how to switch collection views based on an action on the segmented control?

Comment: How to switch collection views.

Answer (score 3):

What you mean by switching? Actually you can use a single collection view and change the data source of the collection according to the switch value

Add an action for your segmented control to change the data source

```
- (IBAction)changeCollectionViewData:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {

switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
        self.images =self.cars // displays images of cars;
        break;
    case 1:
        self.images =self.bike // displays images of bikes;
        break;
}
[self.collectionView reloadData]

}  
// self.images is the data source array
```

Remember you need to set the **numberOfItemsInSection** accordingly

Comment: Cheers. Might use this approach.